# Return values in cell array based on a condition

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

I have a 1x3 cell array that looks like this:

```
str = strings(6,1)
str(1) = 'A'
str(2) = 'B'
str(3) = 'A'
str(4) = 'B'
str(5) = 'A'
str(6) = 'B'

str2 = strings(6,1)
str(1) = 'r'
str(2) = 'r'
str(3) = 't'
str(4) = 's'
str(5) = 't'
str(6) = 'm'

a = [345; 344; 234; 234; 235; 231]

CA{1} = str
CA{2} = str2
CA{3} = a
```

I need to extract the values in column 3 where:
column 1 shows an `'A'` AND column 2 shows a `'t'`.

I cannot even find a start on how to approach it, hope someone can help me! 
I have tried the codes below, but they return an empty vector, that is probably due to my misspecification of the problem, sorry for that!!

Comment: I'm sorry, didnt think of that :(

Comment: [edit] your question then.

Comment: Okay, I've tried to write it down, I couldn't find how to make a prober table (in the help it said that tables are only possible for documentations) and I could not find how to at least make multiple spaces between the letters/numbers so that it at least looks like a column

Comment: Copy paste  the cell array and use `{ }` to properly format it. btw does your first row actually have `[1]  [2]  [3]` or you wrote it just to show the column number

Comment: Okay, wasn't anticipating such a reaction. Going to give you the code in a second. @SardarUsama: yeah it was just my way of showing the columns, sorry I'm redoing it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use the KISS code (Keep it simple stupid). The method I'm proposing may not be the fastest or the most elegant, but I tried it and it works.

```
% I'm using the length of cellarray{1} as reference, since all cells are the same length
for k = 1:length(cellarray{1})
    if ((cellarray{1}(k) == 'A') && (cellarray{2}(k) == 't'))
        % Assign the value to a new vector, or display the value... But this is how you get to it.
        disp(cellarray{3}(k));
    end
end
```

I called your cell array *cellarray* in this example. You could also use [strcmp](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) instead of ==, in fact you will need to if ever you're comparing more than just one character.

Answer (score 0):

The following bit of code might be suitable:

```
cellArray{3}((cellArray{1}=='A')&(cellArray{2}=='t'))
```

Where `cellArray{3}` is the column of the cell array from which you want the values, and `cellArray{1}` and `cellArray{2}` are the columns containing the characters.  This should return a matrix containing the numeric values.

I hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [cellfun](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html). You want to index into the 3rd element of each cell, so create a function which indexes into the 3rd element of a value, and then apply this to each cell:

```
>> cellfun(@(c) c(3), CA,'UniformOutput',false)

ans =

  1×3 cell array

    {["A"]}    {["t"]}    {[234]}
```

Comment: I ran that code but it yields: ans =

  1×3 cell array

    ["t"]    [""]    [234]
for me

Comment: This is because you have a bug in the code of your problem statement. You preallocate the second set of strings into str2, but all of the assignments are made into str, which leave str2 unchanged and overwrite all the content of str with what you meant to go into str2